# WPF MVVM - Image source is empty even though I set it at the ViewModel ctor

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm working on an MVVM WPF project at work.

I'm trying to load an image at the ViewModel's ctor within a certain timespan.

If successful - display the window with the preloaded image, if unsuccessful, I'm setting a URL to another image control for the WPF to load after the window appears.

The purpose is to avoid displaying the window and then waiting for the image to load. Instead, I'm willing to wait up to that timespan in order to get the 'complete' window with the image.

Here's my viewModel:

```
    public BitmapImage ImageSource { get; set; }
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
    public VM1()
    {
        _log.Info("Starting");
        GetImageSourceOrUrl(@"https://images-cdn.9gag.com/photo/aBxzjdx_460s.jpg", 100);
        _log.Info("displaying window");       
    }

    private void GetImageSourceOrUrl(string url, int timeout)
    {
        ImageUrl = url;
        var getImageBitmapTask = GetImageBitmapTask(url);
        getImageBitmapTask.Wait(timeout); //wait until timeout or image load
        if (getImageBitmapTask.IsCompleted)
        {
            ImageSource = getImageBitmapTask.Result;
            _log.Info($"image from Bitmap");
        }
        else
        {
            _log.Warn($"image from URL {ImageUrl}");
        }
    }

    private Task<BitmapImage> GetImageBitmapTask(string imageUrl)
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<BitmapImage>();
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            _log.Info("trying to download the image");
            var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri(imageUrl));
            if (bitmapImage.IsDownloading)
            {
                bitmapImage.DownloadCompleted += (s, e) =>
                {
                    _log.Info("finished downloading");
                    bitmapImage.Freeze();
                    tcs.TrySetResult(bitmapImage);
                };
            }
            else
            {
                _log.Info("already have the image");
                bitmapImage.Freeze();
                tcs.TrySetResult(bitmapImage);
            }
            Dispatcher.Run(); //keep this thread alive
        });
        return tcs.Task;
    }
```

And the XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="207" Margin="339,167,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="359"
           Source="{Binding ImageSource}" 
           Visibility="{Binding Path=ImageSource, Converter={StaticResource NullToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
    <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="207" Margin="339,167,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="359"
           Source="{Binding ImageUrl}" 
           Visibility="{Binding Path=ImageUrl, Converter={StaticResource StringToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
</Grid>
```

I'm encountering 2 issues:
1. How come the 'displaying window' log appears before the 'image from bitmap' appears, regardless of the timeout parameter? doesn't Task.Wait suppose to block?
2. As you can see I'm using converters at the XAML. they work fine (didn't want to overload the question), and when I debug it, I can see the URL of the second image control was set.
However, with Snoop, the Source property of the second image is empty... How come?

Comment: Loading a BitmapImage from a remote URL is inherently asynchronous. Check the IsDownloading property and attach a DownloadCompleted event handler. Or do the download manually.

Comment: Thanks @Clemens, I edited the question and added the task implementation where I check the 'isDownloading' property and attaching a DownloadCompleted event handler, yet this doesn't work

Comment: Not sure why you need that Task. You could use the DownloadCompleted event and the Tick event of a DispatcherTimer in parallel, and handle whatever occurs first.

Comment: @Clemens I tried what you suggested, at the ctor I used a DispatcherTimer that sets the ImageUrl on a tick, and also created the bitmap which on DownloadCompleted event sets the ImageSource.  
But, how can I block the ctor? so that it won't return until the timer ticks?
otherwise the timer ticks only after returning from the ctor

Comment: You can't do that, because the constructor is also called in the UI thread.

Comment: @Clemens, when zooming out on the problem I tried to solve - how do you suggest handling this scenario: at the XAML I set the source to ImageUrl property, which is a link to a large image. When the app starts, the user sees a blank window and needs to wait for the View to finish loading the image. only after the loading completes the View is updated with the just-downloaded image. It makes more sense to display the window only after the image has already been loaded (which is what I tried to do - preload at the ViewModel, with a timeout).      Your help is much appreciated! thanks

Comment: "*It makes more sense to display the window only after the image has already been loaded*" - not in my opinion. If there is a Window already open that is supoosed to show an image that is currently being downloaded, show a placeholder image, a loading animation or something similar in the meantime.